# JPG files from Leica Q2M cannot be opened, Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: sd-card, gimp, jpeg

I've tried `geeqie`, `ristretto`, `gimp`, and the browsers, and nothing seems to be able to open the JPG files produced by a Leica Q2 Monochrom. They all get various errors about the file format. The `file` output for the JPG files looks fine, which I know doesn't mean much but the files are there and it knows that they're JPG files. However, as far as I can tell nothing in my Ubuntu installation can open them.

I can try them on a Windows machine, but that'll take a little while.

*edit* — the main error seems to be "Unsupported marker type 0x66"

*edit more* — this seems to have been a problem with the built-in SD card reader in the laptop. When I use an external USB reader, probably 5 years newer than the laptop, things work fine.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `gimp some_file.jpg` and also: `exiv2 some_file.jpg` Where 'some_file' is a jpg you are having trouble opening.

Comment: Can you post a sample file online somewhere?

Comment: @andrew.46 I'm working on it; the problem is very bizarre. I have some suspicions that it may have to do with the 2013 laptop I'm using. Some SD cards work fine, others don't, and that spans cameras, so it's really weird.

Comment: OK I tried a different USB SD reader and the problem went away. This old laptop is worse than I thought it was. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: @chili555 no software could open the files; they failed with various random errors. I have pretty good evidence that it's simply a hardware/firmware problem with the laptop's built-in card reader.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have been a problem with the built-in card reader in the old Dell Inspiron I'm using. An external reader does not have the problems.